# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required "required directory"

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel

I am uploading laravel project to cpanel ,I have set the path in `index.php`
but it return the fatel error

> error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/customer/www/easy-websites.online/public_html/../quickquiz/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php73/pear') in /home/customer/www/easy-websites.online/public_html/index.php on line 24
```

I have not seperate directory for `quickapp` but it show in error
I am uploading all my project files and folder in `public_html`

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**.htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**file structure**

```
publichtml{
app
bootstrap
etc..
index.php
.htaccess
vendor { autoload.php}
}
```

`index.php` and `.htaccess` under public_html and `autoload.php` under vendor folder

Answer (score 0):

Deploy laravel app on Cpanel requires some different steps and can be handled by different ways for me this is the best way
we can summarize in

1. uploading files inside laravel public folder to Cpanel public_html
2. create another directory in Cpanel /home that will contain the rest of your laravel app (at the same level of Public_html)
3. upload the rest of the files exclude public to the new directory you just created
4. Open the index.php file on public_html/index.php and Replace the require path to be `./../YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME/vendor/autoload.php`
5. same for bootstrap in the same file replace app.php require path to the correct path by adding Your DIRECTORY_NAME
6. you may also need to change the import path of index.php in your DIRECTORY_NAME/server.php file

For more information and a good explanation with images you can follow this tutorial [Deploy Laravel Project on Shared Hosting CPanel](https://igniz87.medium.com/deploy-laravel-project-on-shared-hosting-cpanel-938b705ebe5a)

Comment: I followed the same step problem is that it show some folder that is not present in cpannel I think it cpanel cache issue

Comment: you need to make sure that you upload all files including vendor directory since you can't run composer install on Cpanel, is vendor directory uploaded ?